# PDFNet - how do I get all bookmarks

Tags: c#, pdf, bookmarks

I'm using the PDFnet SDK for c#. I want to list in my own window all bookmarks.

However, I find the only way to get to the first bookmark, but not the other bookmarks.

this is my code:

```
namespace David.PDFTest
{
    public partial class PDFView : PDFViewCtrl
    {
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(GetDoc().GetFirstBookmark().GetTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

is there the possibility to get all the bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a [`Bookmark.GetNext()`](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/PDFNetAPIRef/html/c46d24dc-c60c-0131-e182-3eee74e687a4.htm) method which you could use.

So I would write something like this:

```
namespace David.PDFTest
{
    public partial class PDFView : PDFViewCtrl
    {
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {   
            var bm = GetDoc().GetFirstBookmark();
            while ( bm!=null )
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(bm.GetTitle());
                bm = bm.GetNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```